# On the "hydra set" $S=\left\{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{x_n}:(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\text{ is an increasing sequence of positive natural numbers}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, egyptian-fractions

What are all the elements of set 
$$ S=\left\{ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{x_n} \right\}$$ where $ (x_n)_{n\geq 1} $ is any increasing sequence of positive natural numbers for which $ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{x_n} $ converges?

Comment: I changed my original answer, because it didn't apply to the changed question (grrr...). It may be of some interest.

Answer (score 5):

Any real number in $(0,1]$ can be written as 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{d_k}{2^k}$$
with $d_k\in\{0,1\}$ with infinite digits $d_k=1$. Now note that
$$\mathbb{R}^+=(0,1]\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(S_n,S_n+1]$$
where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}$ (recall that $S_n\to+\infty$, as $n\to\infty$). Hence, after rearranging the odd numbers and the powers of $2$, in ascending order, we may conclude that
$$\left\{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{x_n}:(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\text{ is a strictly increasing sequence in $\mathbb{N}^+$}\right\}=\mathbb{R}^+.$$

Comment: Thanks, great solution!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edit my answer with a full solution.

Comment: @RobertZ: now your answer is way more elegant than mine. A (+1) with envy :D

Answer (score 4):

Every element of $\mathbb{Q}^+$ belongs to such set by a well-known statement about [Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction).
For instance
$$ \frac{13}{19}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{57} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{114}+\frac{1}{228}+\frac{1}{456}+\ldots $$

On the other hand, if $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ it is simple to construct a series of the wanted form which is convergent to $\alpha$. We take $k\in\mathbb{N}$ as the greater value such that $H_k<\alpha$. Then we take $n_1$ as the least integer such that $n_1\geq k+1$ and $\frac{1}{n_1}<\alpha-H_k$. Then we take $n_2$ as the least integer such that $n_2\geq n_1+1$ and $\frac{1}{n_2}<\alpha-H_k-\frac{1}{n_1}$. Continuing this way,
$$ \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+\ldots = \alpha. $$
It follows that the wanted set is just $\mathbb{R}^+$.

---

$$\pi = H_{12}+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{744}+\frac{1}{1173268}+\ldots $$

---

An interesting remark is that $(S,+)$ is a semigroup due to [the hydra paradox](http://www.slate.com/blogs/quora/2014/06/04/hydra_game_an_example_of_a_counterintuitive_mathematical_result.html). If we consider $\alpha,\beta\in S$ and simply add the associated representation terms of the form $\frac{2}{m}$ might appear. On the other hand the first term with such a structure (or an even larger numerator) can be written as the sum of unit fractions with larger denominators, and by iterating this process "from the left to the right" we [eventually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction)$^{(*)}$ reach a representation of $\alpha+\beta$ as the sum of unit fractions with distinct denominators. The [Erdos-Straus conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture) states that the hydra we are fighting against has a "degree of ramification" bounded by $4$.

<sup>(*) Please see the exchange between I and [Wojowu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127263/wojowu?tab=profile) in the comments below, too.
 I am really grateful to him for raising some interesting points.</sup>

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your remark about the semigroup being like a hydra. If we are not careful with how we decompose $2/m$ into Egyptian fractions, we might as well have an infinite battle. If we have in the decomposition two fractions $2/m$ and $1/n$, we can split $1/m$ into a sum which involves $1/n$, and some other fractions, so we end up with something involving $2/n$ and, say, $1/p$. This way we will always have a repeated fraction.

Comment: @Wojowu: we may resolve the situations like $\frac{2}{m}$ or $\frac{N}{m}$ one at a time, by starting with the smallest value of $m$ for which they occur. Sooner or later, the hydra will die and we will have a representation for an element of $S$.

Comment: I just gave an argument for how it might never happen that the hydra will die. We can arrange the reductions so that at each step there is a fraction $2/m$ followed by a fraction $1/n,n>m$.

Comment: @Wojowu: I am just saying that once you re-write $\frac{2}{m}$ as $\frac{1}{N_1}+\frac{1}{N_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{N_k}$ (with each $N_j>m$) the problem at the denominator $=m$ is no more there. You may have a bigger problem at the denominator $m+1$, of course, with an even bigger numerator. And you can write $\frac{M}{m+1}$ as $\frac{1}{M_1}+\frac{1}{M_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{M_h}$ with $M_f>m+1$. Sooner or later there won't be troublesome denominators.

Comment: How would you prove that "Sooner or later there won't be troublesome denominators"? The article you link to only proves that a very specific hydra, quite different from the one you use, always dies.

Comment: @Wojowu: at the $m$-th step of our resolution algorithm all the denominators $\leq m$ are associated with a unit numerator. We are allowed to consider the limit as $m\to +\infty$ because no matter what, at each step the set of troublesome denominators has asymptotic density zero, since the harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: Hm, if you allow making infinitely many steps (which is what you do when taking the limit $m\to\infty$), then I agree everything is fine. However, with finitely many steps, I still claim it isn't always possible.

Comment: @Wojowu: I would ask you to provide an explicit counter-example, but I guess the existence of such counter-examples depends on the model of Arithmetics we are assuming (no, this is gibberish). I would just point out that we do not need to fix the representation with finitely many steps: to fix it in $\omega$ steps is just fine. And at the $m$-th step, the sum of the egyptian fractions with denominators $\leq m$ we got becomes a more and more accurate approximation of $\alpha+\beta$ as $m\to +\infty$.

Comment: Existence of counterexamples doesn't need any assumption on the model of arithmetic. Start with, for example, 2/2+1/3. Proceed writing 1/2=1/3+1/6, so we get 1/2+2/3+1/6. Proceed writing (for example) 1/3=1/6+1/9+1/18. We get 1/2+1/3+2/6+1/9+1/18. Proceed writing 1/6=1/9+(some other fractions). We get 1/2+1/3+1/6+2/9+1/18+... We then write 1/9=1/18+... to get 1/2+1/3+1/6+1/9+2/18+... I hope you see the pattern here - we construct the sequence so that there always is a fraction with 2 in the numerator. Working out further steps is somewhat tedious, but by no means impossible (see next comment)

Comment: Note that the parts of the expansion with numerator 1 do converge to the desired result, I am not denying that. I am just talking about all the intermediate steps we are getting and how they all contain a non-Egyptian fraction.

Comment: @Wojowu: all right, but the limit representation $\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}$ (or the correct one) is fine. I agree we do not get it in a finite number of steps, but we don't have to. For future readers: we are not arguing or disagreeing, we are just clarifying what we mean by *eventually*. In my answer *eventually* stands for *in time $\omega$*, while Wojowu has just provided a representation which cannot be fixed in a finite time.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to point out that if $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive terms, with $a_n\to 0$ and $\sum a_n = \infty,$ then for any $x>0,$ there exists an infinite subset $A\subset \mathbb N$ such that

$$\tag 1 x = \sum_{n\in A}a_n.$$

I'll omit the proof except to say it proceeds by finding "disjoint" subsums $S_1,S_2,\dots $ of $\sum a_n$ such that $S_1 + S_2 + \cdots = x.$ (The set $A$ is then the set of all indices used in any of the the $S_n$'s.)

It follows that if  $n_1,n_2, \dots $ is any strictly increasing sequence of positive integers such that

$$\tag 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_{k}} = \infty,$$

then given $x>0,$ there's an infinite subsum of $(2)$ that converges to $x.$

Corollary: any $x>0$ is the infinite sum of reciprocals of distinct primes.